# Finding a functional which has critical function satisfying: $\nabla\cdot B = 0$, $\nabla\times B=0$.

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

How can I find a functional that has a minimum satisfying the PDE
$$
\begin{cases}
\nabla\cdot \mathbf{B}  = 0 & \text{on }\Omega\,,\\
\nabla\times \mathbf{B} = 0 & \text{on }\Omega\,,\\
\mathbf{B}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{n}}=0 & \text{on }\partial\Omega\, ,
\end{cases}
$$
where $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$ is a vector normal to the surface of $\Omega$ and $\Omega\in\mathbb{R}^3$. In my case the domain $\Omega$ is such that there exists a vector field $\mathbf{A}$ such that $B = \nabla\times\mathbf{A}$, so the above PDE can be written as
$$
\begin{cases}
\nabla\times(\nabla\times \mathbf{A}) = 0 & \text{on }\Omega\,,\\
(\nabla\times \mathbf{A})\cdot\hat{\mathbf{n}}=0 & \text{on }\partial\Omega\, .
\end{cases}
$$
Note that there should be a nonzero solution to this PDE since my domain has the topology of a torus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Hodge decomposition gives you that $B$ is harmonic on $\Omega$ and thus minimizes the vector Dirichlet energy
$$E(v) = (\nabla \cdot v)^2 + \|\nabla \times v\|^2.$$
Of course, so does the zero vector field, so you will need to bar it by adding, say, a norm constraint:
$$B = \underset{v}{\operatorname{argmin}} \int_{\Omega} \left[(\nabla \cdot v)^2 + \|\nabla \times v\|^2\right]\,dV \quad \mathrm{s.t.}\quad \begin{array}{c}\langle v, \hat{n}\rangle=0 \mathrm{\ on\ } \partial \Omega,\\ \int_{\Omega} \|v\|^2\,dV = 1.\end{array}$$

Comment: Do you know of any books that study the Dirichlet energy of vector fields? I've seen the Dirichlet energy before, but for classical real valued harmonic functions that minimise $\int_\Omega||\nabla\phi||^2\,\text{d}V$. Also, if $B$ is a harmonic vector field, then does it satisfy some sort of maximum principle?